# Creating new symbol derived from hash

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have rotated the hash `#` by about 45 degrees using the command:

```
\newcommand{\hash}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\#$}}}
```

I used it:

```
\[
\B(\R^n) = \B(\R^r) \hash_{\sigma} \B(\R^s) \text{, gdzie }
\]
\[
\B(\R^r) \hash_{\sigma} \B(\R^s) = \sigma(\{ A \times B : A \in
\B(\R^r), B \in \B(\R^s) \})
\]
```

and it looks like:

[image]

but it doesn't look beautiful. I would like to ask how can I make the symbol inside the red polygon in a more elegant way.

Comment: How should it look like exactly and have you checked [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use two rotated `\parallel` symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\hash{\mathbin{\mathpalette\xhash\relax}}
\newcommand{\xhash}[2]{\ooalign{%
  $#1\xxhash{#1}{-45}$\cr
  $#1\xxhash{#1}{45}$\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\xxhash}[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#2}{$#1\parallel$}}

\begin{document}
$a \hash_{\sigma} b_{\hash}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Package `unicode-math` with LuaTeX/XeTeX

The rotated hash symbol is available as Unicode symbol:

```
U+2A33 SMASH PRODUCT
```

Latin Modern Math does not contain the symbol, but Asana-Math and the XITS fonts. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

%\setmathfont[version=smashfont]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[version=smashfont]{xits-math.otf}

\newcommand*{\hash}{%
  \mathpalette\setsmashfont\smashtimes
}
\newcommand*{\setsmashfont}[2]{%
  \mbox{%
    \mathversion{smashfont}%
    $\mathsurround=0pt#1#2$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathcal{B}(\BbbR^r) \hash_{\sigma} \mathcal{B}(\BbbR^s)
\]

\end{document}
```

Result for `Asana-Math.otf`:

> [image: Asana]

Result for `xits-math.otf`:

> [image: xits]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one interpretation...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackMath
\def\newhash{\mathrel{\abovebaseline[-.8ex]{\rotatebox{45}{\stackon[0pt]{%
\stackon[0pt]{\rule[.31em]{1em}{.1em}}{\rule[.64em]{1em}{.1em}}%
}{\rule{.1em}{1em}\rule{.2em}{0pt}\rule{.1em}{1em}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[X \newhash_\sigma Y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackMath
\def\newhash{\mathrel{\abovebaseline[-.9ex]{\rotatebox{45}{\stackon[0pt]{%
\stackon[0pt]{\rule[.31em]{1em}{.08em}}{\rule[.64em]{1em}{.08em}}%
}{\rule{.08em}{1em}\rule{.23em}{0pt}\rule{.08em}{1em}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[X \newhash_\sigma Y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]